# apt-get only downloading gnome classic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, gnome, desktop-environments

For the past few weeks, I've been having a problem with my two laptops. Somehow (both on linux mint 13 and ubuntu 12.04) I have been trying to download gnome 3.4 shell. Unfortunately it would only install the classic mode instead of the normal Gnome mode with effects.

I did download it correctly (after adding the ppa, etc) what could the problems me?

Answer (score 0):

You probably do have the gnome-shell installed, but it is starting in fallback mode.

Is your graphics card 3d-enabled? You might want to check the output of "/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p" in a terminal, and then go on the hunt for some "Additional Drivers".